# Send data back to rootviewcontroller before a popToRootViewController method call?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller

What is the best way to send data back to the root view controller before calling the popToRootViewControllerAnimated method? I am trying to signal to the rootviewcontroller that the current viewcontroller no longer exists and keep a record of what viewcontroller has been pushed thru segue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mustn't wait until the current view controller "no longer exists". While the current view controller does exist, the root view controller is the current view controller's `navigationController.viewControllers[0]`. So you have the reference you need to send a message from this one to that one. Just cast to the root view controller's class and now you can call any public method in the root view controller, e.g.

```
MyRootViewController* rvc = (MyRootViewController*)(self.navigationController.viewControllers[0]);
rvc.coolData = myCoolData;
```

Comment: By the way, the general problem of getting a reference from one object to another in iOS programming is discussed in my book, here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch13.html#_instance_visibility

Comment: Sounds good; thanks. Would you say this method is deemed appropriate in terms of Objective-C standards and the whole idea of OO?

Answer (score 2):

There are two basic ways to do this: 1) with an NSNotification message or 2) with a delegate call. There are plenty of tutorials on how to code both. I wrote a small delegate tutorial as an answer to this question: [Back button in iphone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272843/back-button-in-iphone-app/10273551#10273551) and you can find a great NSNotification tutorial here: [Send and receive messages through NSNotificationCenter in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass UINavigationController and override the necessary methods to track your array.  I would recommend keeping a uniqued set of titles for each view controller popped off the stack.  As for signaling to the current view controller that the previous view controller doesn't exist, that's what `-viewWillAppear` is for.  If you need finer-grain control, create a protocol for your View Controller instances to conform to that the navigation controller calls out to when it pops one or more of them off the stack.